# Unity Ads test mode false but it is showing test ad every time

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityads

I published my mobile game on google play and after publishing I set the unity test mode to false on my database. Since I got this data from the database, I don't need to update the game again. Unity test mode comes true or false but no matter what the situation is always unity example ads appear as if test mode is true.
There is my code : https://codeshare.io/vwPEol
I would greatly appreciate it if you could help or advise!

Answer (score 0):

Proper way is to just show test ads only on debug builds.

```
if (Debug.isDebugBuild)
{
 _testMode = true;
 }else{
 _testMode = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Unity Dashboard>Settings there is an option called "Test mode". That can force Test Mode regardless of the mode programmatically set on a device. Turn that off.